# Power and volume buttons are broken and I can't turn on my Samsung phone

Tags: samsung, buttons, power-on

My Samsung phone's power and volume buttons are broken and I can't turn on the phone. Is there a way to power the phone on? Maybe with something external like a keyboard?

Comment: Sorry, no, there isn't. If it's valuable send it to repair.